Computing $\oint_{|z|=1}\frac1{iz}\exp\Bigl(-iy\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}4(z-\frac1z)^2}\Bigr)\,\mathrm dz$
Trying to come up with a closed form to the integral in this post, I ended up with this contour integral,
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\dfrac{e^{-iy\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{4}\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)^2}}}{iz}\,\mathrm dz,$$
which if integrated wrt $y$ over $[0,k]$ yields the answer the author is looking for.
I've already found the branch points which are
$$
\begin{matrix}
z_1=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a}; &\enspace z_2=\dfrac{1-\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a}\\
z_3=-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a}; &\enspace z_4=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+a^2}}{a},
\end{matrix}
$$
and what's left is determining whether the origin is or not a singularity. Once that is done I thought the next step could be developing a Laurent series of the integrand that would converge where there are no branch cuts, but I'm having issues in doing so... Another idea could be that if the contour passes through a branch cut we could come up with another contour which would be the sum of $|z|=1$ and the ones detouring the branch cuts. By Cauchy's integral theorem that integral would be $0$, and thus, our integral, should just be minus the sum of the rest of line integrals.That's why I'm asking for assistance.

I have no clue how to solve the problem.  However, I strongly suspect that the approach taken by the original poster, while it might actually solve the problem, is not what the problem composer intended.  My inference is based on two things: (1)  $~|z| = 1 \iff z~$ is expressible as $~e^{i\theta} = \cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta).~$ and (2) $~|z| = 1 \implies \left[ ~z - \dfrac{1}{z} ~\right] = 2i\sin(\theta),~$ which is a purely imaginary number.

In the linked post, the argument of the exponential reappears as the denominator, but not here. Is it an omission ? Alos, did you try to determine the Laurent expansion around $z = 0$ of the integrand ?

The linked post integral can be written as
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^k\exp\left(-iy\sqrt{1+a^2\sin^2(x)}\right),\mathrm dy,\mathrm dx$$
If we interchange order of integration we get
$$\int_0^k\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\exp\left(-iy\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{4}\left(z-\frac{1}{z}\right)^2}\right)}{iz},\mathrm dy$$
